SSD Keeps Disconnected (Kingston KC3000)
I have a Kingston KC3000 2TB SSD.
The model number is skc3000d2048g.
This drive was fine for 2 years. The Kingston software says the drive is fine.
However, quite frequently, the drive starts behaving as if all of the files are missing or corrupt, until the system is rebooted. The drive still appears in File Explorer (as D:), and I can browse the folders and files. However, if I try to open a file from File Explorer, an error dialog appears that says "A device which does not exist was specified."
What could be causing this? What can I do to troubleshoot it?

Here is the SMART info from CrystalDiskInfo:
-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 000000000000 Critical Warning
02 000000000133 Composite Temperature
03 000000000064 Available Spare
04 00000000000A Available Spare Threshold
05 000000000002 Percentage Used
06 0000014412BF Data Units Read
07 0000050745E7 Data Units Written
08 000006F13A71 Host Read Commands
09 00004875F533 Host Write Commands
0A 000000000BBF Controller Busy Time
0B 000000000052 Power Cycles
0C 00000000372E Power On Hours
0D 00000000000E Unsafe Shutdowns
0E 000000000000 Media and Data Integrity Errors
0F 0000000001BC Number of Error Information Log Entries

Here is the SMART info from Kingston SSD Manager:
[SMART Data]
######## Dump Smart Data ########,,,
ID(HEX),                                       Description,         Raw Value,Unit
      0,                                  Critical Warning,0x0000000000000000,-,
      1,                             Composite Temperature,0x0000000000000142,K,
      2,                                   Available Spare,0x0000000000000064,%,
      3,                         Available Spare Threshold,0x000000000000000a,%,
      4,                                   Percentage Used,0x0000000000000002,%,
      5,                                   Data Units Read,0x00000000014495a3,1000 unit,
      6,                                Data Units Written,0x00000000050a194d,1000 unit,
      7,                                Host Read Commands,0x0000000006f48c03,Count,
      8,                               Host Write Commands,0x00000000489ea64c,Count,
      9,                              Controller Busy Time,0x0000000000000bca,Mins,
     0A,                                      Power Cycles,0x0000000000000052,Count,
     0B,                                    Power On Hours,0x0000000000003755,Count,
     0C,                                  Unsafe Shutdowns,0x000000000000000e,Count,
     0D,                   Media and Data Integrity Errors,0x0000000000000000,Count,
     0E,                  Number of Error Info Log Entries,0x00000000000001bc,Count,
     0F,                Warning Composite Temperature Time,0x0000000000000000,Mins,
     10,               Critical Composite Temperature Time,0x0000000000000000,Mins,
     11,                              Temperature Sensor 1,0x0000000000000000,K,
     12,                              Temperature Sensor 2,0x0000000000000159,K,
     13,                              Temperature Sensor 3,0x0000000000000000,K,
     14,                              Temperature Sensor 4,0x0000000000000000,K,
     15,                              Temperature Sensor 5,0x0000000000000000,K,
     16,                              Temperature Sensor 6,0x0000000000000000,K,
     17,                              Temperature Sensor 7,0x0000000000000000,K,
     18,                              Temperature Sensor 8,0x0000000000000000,K,
     19, Thermal Management Temperature 1 Transition Count,0x0000000000000000,NA,
     1A, Thermal Management Temperature 2 Transition Count,0x0000000000000000,NA,
     1B,   Total Time For Thermal Management Temperature 1,0x000000000000002d,NA,
     1C,   Total Time For Thermal Management Temperature 2,0x0000000000000000,NA,


Please post the SMART attributes for the disk. If you don't have a product for that, use for example CrystalDiskInfo.

Thank you, @harrymc . I updated the post.

That data looks funny. It should look something like this.

It's an SSD. Those other metrics look like spinning platter metrics.

Yes, but the SMART attributes have the same numbers for both, and yours are not standard. For example 05 is usually "OS Reallocated Sectors Count" while yours is "Percentage Used".

That's odd. A Samsung 970 in the same machine has the same metrics

Here is the screenshot from CrystalDiskInfo. The output for the Samsung 970 looks the same. https://imgur.com/a/k0hR0eX

CrystalDiskInfo might be failing on this disk. Have you tried the Kingston SSD Manager?

Yes. The Kingston SSD manager also reports this disk as healthy.

I intended to ask if the SSD manager reports the same SMART data as CrystalDiskInfo.

I edited to include the export from Kingston SSD Manager. Thank you.

The Kingston SSD SMART attributes are the same as that of CrystalDiskInfo.
Anyway, the parameters do not show any errors. This can be because:
(1) There are no errors, or (2) The firmware is in a bad shape and
no longer updates these statistics.
Option (1) doesn't seem to agree with observation, so you might play
it safe and retire this SSD. A disk that starts behaving strangely
without apparent reason is not safe for your data.
Two years is a short lifetime for a good-quality disk.
However, from the data I can see that the disk was under power
for 24h/7 almost all this time, and this might have contributed
to premature aging (although it shouldn't have mattered).
The quality of any given one disk is mostly a matter of luck.
